# How to get a SPNEGO / Kerberos Session key -and implement HTTP Authentication:Negotiate on my own client

Tags: c, web-services, http-authentication, spnego

I was recently exposed to a new authentication method i had no idea of.
After reading a bit and researching to understand it,I understood it has something to do with SPNEGO, or maybe it is just spnego.

Im running windows xp on a large network, when my browser opens it automatically
connects to a web-service in the network, which requires authentication:

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate

then my browser sends automatically (along with more headers ofcourse):

Authorization: Negotiate (encrypted string).

I concluded this Handshake uses the SPNEGO protocol.

What i need to do, is to create my own client (actually,its a bot that uses this webservice that requires that authentication). I Need to get that encrypted string (exactly like my browser gets it, probably by using some SPNEGO protocol) without any user interaction (again, as my browser).

the thing is, that i don't have enough time to study  the spnego protocol and how to implement one.

I'm using c/c++, but if i have no option c# would be okay as well.
Are there any functions / classes / codes or maybe even good tutorials to help me implement it shortly?

Comment: Why not just use WinINET to send the HTTP request? It which will handle the authentication challenge automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`curl` works with Kerberos/spnego. I'm not sure how well this functionality works on Windows, you should try and see. It works well enough on Linux. You can look at the source to see how it is done.

Comment: Have you ever tested it? It does not work. It claims to support it but the code is a contrib and untested by the maintainers. I had no luck with it. I would consider it broken!

Comment: Yes I have in fact tested it more than once. It works in a product that I develop so I'm more or less familiar with its functionality. There are some bugs but it is mostly working. What kind of problems do you have with it? Have you tried `curl` from the command line? With what arguments?

Comment: I simply was not able to compile fbopenssl with cURL. The was not configure script and a crappy makefile. Even those guys on the mailinglist had no clue because it is a contribution.

Comment: I am not sure why you wasn't able to compile it. It compiles for me out of the box on several Linux flavors (with warnings, but they are harmless). This is not a pinnacle of software engineering but it does work.

Comment: You do need to install OpenSSL development package in order to compile fbopenssl. If you tell me what kind of compilation errors you are getting I might be able to help you.

Comment: After your reply I tried to compile everything again on FreeBSD. After a feew FBOpenSSL makefile mods all compiled well. Now curl does not process the SPNEGO token. I see that the ticket is request and available in klist but it still fails:
`* gss_init_sec_context() failed: : unknown mech-code 51183616 for mech unknowngss_init_sec_context() failed: : No error: 0(WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate`
Subversion with libneon runs perfectly, so Kerberos works as desired.
I have no clue anymore.

Comment: This is probably a configuration problem. Do you have MIT Kerberos or Heimdal? I think this error shows up with Heimdal but I personally have never seen it. I always work with MIT. I can try to troubleshoot your problem, but no guarantees as I have no experience with Heimdal. Do you want to give it a try?

Comment: Yes, Heimdal is default on FreeBSD. I know that my Kerberos setup is fine because Subversion works perfectly with libneon and SPNEGO. I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: OK, show your `/etc/krb5.conf`, output of `klist` and of `curl -v -u : your-url`, I'll look at it. By the way here's what my `curl` outputs:  http://pastebin.com/hACpEb36 (output truncated, real hostname and IP removed)

Comment: He-he, I haven't read TFM back than either. Spent a few hours on this one.

Comment: Anyway, this really confusing and should be fixed. Could have spared us the wasted time. Btw, FBOpenSSL is extremely old and has been written when there was not SPNEGO support in MIT or Heimdal. Right now but do natively according to their docs. If a get some free time I will rewrite cURL with my humble C knowledge and rely on GSS-API only. FBOpenSSL has a broken Makefile and not configure script. Really archaic.